# java interface Path extends more than one class, bug?

Tags: java, path, extends

I just find that interface Path has extended 3 class, which against the principle;

```
public interface Path
extends Comparable<Path>, Iterable<Path>, Watchable
```

????

Comment: no. an interface can extend several other interfaces (not classes)

Comment: @deHaar code as picture instead of text is no improvement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extends` keyword is used with interfaces to make them extend other interfaces (that is not extending multiple classes).

All the types after the `extends` keyword of `Path` are interfaces (`Comparable`, `Iterable`, and `Watchable`).